# Союз "как... так и"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как"? Знаю, что перед составным союзом "как... так и" запятая не ставится, но здесь как будто определительный оборот: программы (какие?) "как ориентированные на отраслевые нужды (атомная энергетика, нефтегазовая промышленность, химические производства), так и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам".

Разработать унифицированные программы аттестации и испытаний вновь конструируемой арматуры различного назначения (,) как ориентированные на отраслевые нужды (атомная энергетика, нефтегазовая промышленность, химические производства), так и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы поставил тире:

*Разработать унифицированные программы аттестации и испытаний вновь конструируемой арматуры различного назначения -- как..., так и...*

Answer (score 0):

Смысл предложения не очень ясен.

Во-первых, союз КАК...ТАК И должен соединять противопоставленные по какому-либо признаку предметы, например: как отечественные (внутренние), так и зарубежные.

Во-вторых, к чему относится выражение"различного назначения"? Это различная арматура или это две различные категории программ? Если это два вида программ, то можно поставить двоеточие. Если это разная арматура, то лучше поставить присоединительное тире.

В тоже время использование таких СИЛЬНЫХ знаков мне не кажется обязательным: оборот можно представить в виде  ряда однородных членов, связанных союзом КАК...ТАК И, и обособить ЗАПЯТОЙ.

ПРЕДЛАГАЕМЫЙ ВАРИАНТ

"Разработать унифицированные программы аттестации и испытаний вновь конструируемой арматуры различного назначения, как ориентированные на (внутренние) отраслевые нужды (атомная энергетика, нефтегазовая промышленность, химические производства), так и отвечающие зарубежным стандартам".